# How to make a spinning circle animation during a countdown in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a time widget that counts down 30 seconds. I have a circle around the time (I attached a screenshot below). I need to animate this circle so that when the time is counted down for 30 seconds, the circle spins, only the time reaches 00:00 the circle stops and does not spin, by pressing the button, the time counts down again for 30 seconds and the circle starts spinning. Tell me how to make an animation of a spinning circle?

```
class ResendLoader extends StatelessWidget {
  const ResendLoader({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    context.read<TimerBloc>().add(const TimerStarted(duration: 30));
    return BlocBuilder<TimerBloc, TimerState>(
      buildWhen: (prev, state) => prev.runtimeType != state.runtimeType,
      builder: (context, state) {
        return Center(
          child: Stack(
            alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                width: 70,
                height: 70,
                child: CustomPaint(
                  painter: RingPainter(
                      progress: 0.3,
                      taskCompletedColor: Colors.white,
                      taskNotCompletedColor:
                          constants.Colors.greyDark.withOpacity(0.5)),
                ),
              ),
              _timerText(context),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }


class CirclePainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final strokeWidth = size.width / 15.0;
    final center = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
    final radius = (size.width - strokeWidth) / 2;
    var paint1 = Paint()
      ..color = const Color(0xff63aa65)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    //a circle
    canvas.drawCircle(center, radius, paint1);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AnimatedRotation widget and animate its turns like this

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(home: AnimatedCircle());
  }
}

class AnimatedCircle extends StatefulWidget {
  const AnimatedCircle({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AnimatedCircle> createState() => _AnimatedCircleState();
}

class _AnimatedCircleState extends State<AnimatedCircle> {
  double rotation = 0;
  int seconds = 30;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            MaterialButton(
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: Text("Start Animation"),
                onPressed: () {
                  seconds = 30;
                  rotation = 0;
                  startAnimation();
                }),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            MaterialButton(
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: Text("Stop Animation"),
                onPressed: () {
                  seconds = 0;
                  setState(() {});
                }),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            AnimatedRotation(
              turns: rotation,
              duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
              curve: Curves.linear,
              child: Stack(
            alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                width: 70,
                height: 70,
                child: CustomPaint(
                  painter: RingPainter(
                      progress: 0.3,
                      taskCompletedColor: Colors.white,
                      taskNotCompletedColor:
                          constants.Colors.greyDark.withOpacity(0.5)),
                ),

            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Text("Seconds: $seconds")
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  startAnimation() {
    
  //To slow down the animation 
    rotation += 0.5;
    seconds--;
    setState(() {});
    if (seconds >= 0) {
      Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
        startAnimation();
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how this code can be connected to my code?

Comment: tell me how can I slow down the scrolling speed?

Comment: And yet, my time starts to report when the animation is over, but how to make the animation last and immediately change the time?

Comment: Updated my answer again. Use rotation += 0.5 for slower animation

Comment: Thank you. I have during the animation, when there is scrolling - the time stands still, when the animation ends, then the time starts the report. How can I make the time report start immediately and the animation work at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Use a FutureBuilder, the future is a this: `Future.delayed(Duration(minutes: 1))`
After a minute, the builder will update to complete. Change the minutes to whatever you want, you can do minutes, seconds, hours, etc.

In the builder, have an if statement to check the status. in the else, return a CircularProgressIndicator widget. That's what you want.

See the docs: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

FYI, you have way more code than you need.